# Else If not working in Javascript Conversion app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

So I'm creating a hybrid mobile JS app and everything is working fine so far until this last else if statement. I'm trying to convert inches to yard. I have the right code down, but its still not working. I only get the same number I type back in the results. What am I doing wrong? I am using Jquery and Jquery Mobile in the app as well.

Heres the HTML bit:

```
<form>
            <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <select name="select-native-3" id="distance" data-iconpos="left">
            <option value="inch">Inch</option>
            <option value="foot">Foot</option>
            <option value="yard">Yard</option>
            <option value="mile">Mile</option>
            <option value="mm">Millimeter</option>
            <option value="m">Meter</option>
            <option value="km">Kilometer</option>
            </select>
            </div>

        <h4>Convert To:</h4>

            <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <select name="select-native-3" id="distanceToo" data-iconpos="left">
            <option value="1">Inches</option>
            <option value="2">Feet</option>
            <option value="3">Yards</option>
            <option value="4">Miles</option>
            <option value="5">Millimeters</option>
            <option value="6">Meters</option>
            <option value="7">Kilometers</option>
            </select>
            </div>  
        </form>
```

Now the JavaScript part:

```
    $("#calcD").on("tap", function() {
        var dist = document.getElementById("inpD").value;   
        var answerAreaD = document.getElementById("ansD");
        var select = document.getElementById("distance");
        var selectToo = document.getElementById("distanceToo");


    if(select.value == "inch" && selectToo.value == "1") {
        answerAreaD.value = dist;
    }

    else if(select.value == "foot" && selectToo.value == "2") {
        answerAreaD.value = dist;
    }

    else if(select.value = "yard" && selectToo.value == "3") {
        answerAreaD.value = dist;
    }

    else if(select.value = "mile" && selectToo.value == "4") {
        answerAreaD.value = dist;
    }

    else if(select.value == "mm" && selectToo.value == "5") {
        answerAreaD.value = dist;
    }

    else if(select.value == "m" && selectToo.value == "6") {
        answerAreaD.value = dist;
    }

    else if(select.value == "km" && selectToo.value == "7") {
        answerAreaD.value = dist;
    }

    else if(select.value == "inch" && selectToo.value == "2") {
        var distInchFeet = dist / 12;
        answerAreaD.value = distInchFeet;
    }

    else if(select.value == "inch" && selectToo.value == "3") {
        var distInchYard = dist * 0.0277777777778;
        answerAreaD.value = distInchYard;
    }

});
```

Comment: `select.value = "mile"`. Remember, `=` is for assignment, `==` or `===` is for comparison.

Comment: select.value = "yard" do remember to change this also. Third else if condition

Comment: Thank you guys as well! everything is working well! I'm still very new to programming but this mistake was embarissing. But thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm curious to see what you'd do if you had 500 comparisons to do. Would you repeat yourself 500 times? Copy and paste the 500 same instructions, over and over? Would you think it's the right thing to do?

Comment: Since you are new to programming Faris I thought you might enjoy looking at a different way to do this without all the copy and pasting of code - https://jsfiddle.net/dr8cua4q/2/

Comment: Apparently iv already written the code and yeah I pretty much copy and pasted all throughout for the else ifs

Answer (score 1):

In all of your `else if` statements you need to have the comparison operator `==` or `===`.  For mile and yard you have `=`, which is assigning the value rather than comparing it.